# Consume Kafka Message using poll mode

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am new to Kafka, and I am using Kafka 1.0.

I read the kafka messages using pull mode, that is, I periodically `poll()`ing the Kafka topic for new messages, but I didn't write the offset back to Kafka.

I would ask how kafka knows that which offsets I have consumed or what is the mechanism that Kafka remembers the progress(Kafka offset)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every consumer group maintains its offset per topic partitions. Since `v0.9` the information of committed offsets for every consumer group is stored in an internal topic called (by default) `__consumer_offsets` (prior to v0.9 this information was stored on Zookeeper). When the offset manager receives an `OffsetCommitRequest`, it appends the request to a special compacted Kafka topic named `__consumer_offsets`. Finally, the offset manager will send a successful offset commit response to the consumer, only when all the replicas of the offsets topic receive the offsets.

Comment: Thanks @giorgos-myrianthous for the helpful answer!